# Asp.net requiredfieldvalidator stops working when using javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

when I add javascript confirm to my button, requiredfieldvalidators stops working

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="add_Click" ID="add" OnClientClick="return confirm('ok?');" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="txt1" ID="rfv1" runat="server" 
            Display="Static" ErrorMessage="Required!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you get some errors?

Comment: No, but form submits with no validation

Comment: Understood. Can you paste the relevant part of the generated HTML with and without the OnClientClick that you have added?

Answer (score 2):

Just add this code to your web.config file and it will work fine

> ```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
>   </appSettings>
> ```

Comment: Please written like this,
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="add_Click" ID="add" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="if (Page_ClientValidate()){ return confirm('ok?')}" CausesValidation="false"  />

Comment: tankyou usha, your comment leads me to answer

Answer (score 1):

add validation group on the button and RequiredFieldValidator and it will work

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have exact answer for you. But there is one solution by using
>   html5 feature.
>
> Just put required inside your textbox field and remove the required
>   field validator.
>
> html5 will take care for validation message too.
>
> It works for me and I'm using HTML5 textbox validations in my project.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" required="true">
```